# update ObservableCollection item without INotifyPropertyChanged in item

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

I have  ObservableCollection playList. This playlist item displays in Listbox. 
All Item update their data in a special thread. I need that only after updating all data, element in listbox updates its info. Actually Is there a way to notify that all data in item changed?
I have 1 solution but it looks bad and moreover in some case it leads to an error.

```
private void AsyncMIReady(MediaItem mediaItem)
{
   if (PlayList.Contains(mediaItem))
   {
       CurSynchronizationContext.Post(delegate(object someState)
             {
                 UpdateItemInPlayList(mediaItem);
             }
                 , null);
    }
 }

public void UpdateItemInPlayList(MediaItem mediaItem)
{
    int i = PlayList.IndexOf(mediaItem);
    PlayList.RemoveAt(i);
    PlayList.Insert(i, mediaItem);
}
```

Comment: You may write `PlayList[i] = mediaItem;` instead of first removing and then inserting the item. This would generate a `CollectionChanged` event with a `Replace` Action that the ListBox will react on.

Comment: Use List<T> instead of ObserableCollection and Notify It as you want.

Comment: Clemens, I tried, but it doesn't work. And i don't now why.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](http://peteohanlon.wordpress.com/2008/10/22/bulk-loading-in-observablecollection/) to be useful. It involves sub-classing ObservableCollection and suspending notifications on AddRange.

```
public class RangeObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
  private bool _suppressNotification = false;

  protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    if (!_suppressNotification)
      base.OnCollectionChanged(e);
  }

  public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> list)
  {
    if (list == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("list");

    _suppressNotification = true;

    foreach (T item in list)
    {
      Add(item);
    }
    _suppressNotification = false;
    OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately Reset rebuild all controls in listbox and it is really heavy procedure. And NotifyCollectionChangedAction hasn't got reset notification for current item.